# Checkout page keeps loading continously in magento 2.2.4

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, error, console

I am using magento 2.2.4.When I checkout from purchase or cart with any product, checkout page start loading details
but checkout keeps loading.
Below console error

[image]

please give me any solution? How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery version 3.3.* is not compatible to Magento 2.2.4,  So just use jquery 1.11.2 to resolve this error

Comment: how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It can be caused by JS. It often happens so that checkout pages are overloaded with extra JS. You can read more in [this guide](https://onilab.com/blog/magento-checkout-slow-fix-it-in-8-simple-steps/). It also describes the most common problems developers usually face when working on checkout. I think it will be quite useful to you.